# Access the return value of the DELETE (Worksheet) dialog

Tags: excel, vba

MSDN says that the worksheet's **Delete** method returns True or False depending upon how the user responded to the confirmation alert. In my version of 2013 Excel this doesn't work. `Debug.Print Sheet1.Delete` gives me a syntax error message, like "Function expected".

I don't want to suppress the alert. But if the user did cancel the deletion I would like to know about it. In fact, the way MSDN describes the action is just what I need. How does this work in the version of Excel I have?

Comment: MSDN doesn't say that :) it says "The Delete method returns a Boolean value that is False if the user chose Cancel on the **dialog box**, or True if the user chose Delete" The dialog box returns the Boolean value. I could be wrong but you cannot directly handle the dialogbox. I would recommend using `Application.Displayalerts = False` to supress the dialogbox and create your own using `Ret = MsgBox("Would you like to delete Sheet1", vbYesNo, "Delete Confirmation")` and then handeling `Ret` using `If Ret = vbYes Then Sheet1.Delete Else MsgBox "User Cancelled"`

Comment: Also using the above method you will still have to do proper error handling to check if the sheet was actually deleted or not...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have read and re-read your rendition of MSDN's info and my own interpretation of it at least a dozen times or more and can't find the difference you seem to be pointing to. To me the accessibility of a "return" is an inalienable property of any return. If the promised Boolean value can't be accessed it's not a "return". However, you are right. There are many workarounds. I've posted the one I used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the user's response to the `Delete` dialog's question isn't available as advertised. Therefore I used the logic that a deleted object shouldn't exist anymore to obtain the same True/False information.

```
            WsLib.Delete
            On Error Resume Next
            Set Rng = WsLib.Cells(1, 1)
            If Err = 0 Then
                Debug.Print "WsLib wasn't deleted"
            End If
            Err.Clear
```

In this code snippet `WsLib` is a worksheet. Application alerts are not suppressed. The attempt to set `Rng` will fail if the worksheet was deleted. Hence, if no error occurs the deletion was halted.

Before this I tried the expression `WsLib Is Nothing` to return False if the user pressed *Cancel* in the alert dialog. Unfortunately that didn't work because `Is Nothing` tests the variable, not the object.

Comment: `Delete dialog's question isn't available as advertised.` It never advertised that it is **available**. It said it returns. Not necessarily that everything that the code returns under the hood will be available to the user. :) BTW the code will fail if there is only 1 worksheet in the workbook but I am guessing that you are already aware of that?